# How to normalize mixed WAV files

Tags: java, android, c++, c, audio

I am trying to mix two WAV files.

The WAV files are available as byte arrays and I am using below code to mix the two.

```
byte[] byte1 , byte[] byte2

// 44 is header of wav file
for( int i = 44 ; i < byte1.length ; i++){
   byte1[i] = byte1[i] + byte2[i];
}
```

The above code mostly works. But when the result is more than maximum wave (16 bit audio file),  it has noise. How can I normalize mixed sound?

Comment: You should be processing it by sample value, not by byte. That's probably pairs of bytes to make 16-bit sample values, but it may not be - you'll need to examine the .wav header to find out. Are there not simple libraries to help you with all of this?

Comment: maybe use another audio codec?

Comment: I dont use any codec, I write in native, by byte to byte, @Rup I did not find any good library for it :(

Comment: Agree with Rup; adding individual bytes doesn't make sense.  You need to be adding 16-bit quantities.

Comment: I have to be adding forth bytes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    short[] audioData1 = null;
    short[] audioData2 = null;

    int n = 0;

    try {
        DataInputStream in1;
        in1 = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("v1.wav"));
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try {

            while ((n = in1.read()) != -1) {
                bos.write(n);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bos.toByteArray());
        bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
        ShortBuffer sb = bb.asShortBuffer();
        audioData1 = new short[sb.capacity()];

        for (int i = 0; i < sb.capacity(); i++) {
            audioData1[i] = sb.get(i);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        DataInputStream in1;
        in1 = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("v2.wav"));
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try {

            while ((n = in1.read()) != -1) {
                bos.write(n);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bos.toByteArray());
        bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
        ShortBuffer sb = bb.asShortBuffer();
        audioData2=  new short[sb.capacity()];

        sb.get(audioData2);


        System.out.println();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // find the max:
    float max = 0;
    for (int i = 22; i < audioData1.length; i++) {
        if (Math.abs(audioData1[i] + audioData2[i]) > max)
            max = Math.abs(audioData1[i] + audioData2[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("" + (Short.MAX_VALUE - max));

    int a, b, c;

    // now find the result, with scaling:
    for (int i = 22; i < audioData1.length; i++) {
        a = audioData1[i];
        b = audioData2[i];

        c = Math.round(Short.MAX_VALUE * (audioData1[i] + audioData2[i])
                / max);

        if (c > Short.MAX_VALUE)
            c = Short.MAX_VALUE;
        if (c < Short.MIN_VALUE)
            c = Short.MIN_VALUE;


        audioData1[i] = (short) c; 

    }

    // to turn shorts back to bytes.
    byte[] end = new byte[audioData1.length * 2];
    ByteBuffer.wrap(end).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().put(audioData1);

    try {
        OutputStream out  = new FileOutputStream("mixer.wav");

        for (int i = 0; i < end.length; i++) {
            out.write(end[i]);
            out.flush();
        }

        out.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

this works, thanks all for answers

Answer (score 4):

First of all, if, indeed, your audio is 16 bits, adding it byte-by-byte won't work. Other people commented on this. You can see my answer here for how to handle this problem.

[using Android's AudioTrack to combine bytes of sound samples produces noise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000933/using-androids-audiotrack-to-combine-bytes-of-sound-samples-produces-noise/11018368)

Secondly, to "normalize" it, you'll have to find the peak first, and then scale all results to that value. That means two loops: one to find the "peak" and one to add the values, scaling to the new peak. Something like this:

```
//this is the raw audio data -- no header
short[] audioData1 , short[] audioData2

//find the max:
float max = 0;
for( int i = 0 ; i < audioData1.length ; i++) {
   if( Math.abs( audioData1[i] + audioData2[i] ) > max )
      max = Math.abs( audioData1[i] + audioData2[i] );
}

//now find the result, with scaling:
for( int i = 0 ; i < audioData1.length ; i++) {
   audioData1[i] = Math.Round(Short.MAX_VALUE * ( audioData1[i] + audioData2[i] ) / max) ;
}
//normalized result in audioData1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    short[] audioData1 = null;
    short[] audioData2 = null;

    int n = 0;

    DataInputStream in1;
    try {
        in1 = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("audio1.wav"));

        audioData1 = new short[in1.available() / 2];
        ShortBuffer b1 = ShortBuffer.wrap(audioData1);
        try {

            while (true) {
                n = in1.readShort();
                b1.put((short) n);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    DataInputStream in2;
    try {
        in2 = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("audio2.wav"));

        audioData2 = new short[in2.available() / 2];
        ShortBuffer b2 = ShortBuffer.wrap(audioData2);
        try {

            while (true) {
                n = in2.readShort();
                b2.put((short) n);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        // find the max:
    float max = 0;
    for (int i = 44; i < audioData1.length; i++) {
        if (Math.abs(audioData1[i] + audioData2[i]) > max)
            max = Math.abs(audioData1[i] + audioData2[i]);
    }

    // now find the result, with scaling:
    for (int i = 44; i < audioData1.length; i++) {
        audioData1[i] = (short) Math.round(Short.MAX_VALUE
                * (audioData1[i] + audioData2[i]) / max);
    }


    DataOutputStream out;

    try {
        out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("mix.wav"));

        for (int i = 0; i < audioData1.length; i++) {
            out.writeShort(audioData1[i]);
            out.flush();
        }

        out.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

now it is in short, it won't work because  value max is 32768 (max short) and nothing changed

Comment: This won't work because you are still reading data as bytes. Note that the arrays in my code are shorts, not bytes.

Comment: That would not work. DataInputStream and DataOutputStream expect the data in network byte order (big endian). It is however very likely that your machine is little endian, so you will get your shorts mixed up in the wrong endianess.

Comment: no, you must byte-swap yourself, but there are wrappers people have written. You can find them by searching right here on stack overflow. Nils is somewhat incorrect: your machine endianness doesn't matter, java is always big endian, but wav files are little endian, hence the backwardness.

Comment: Your new code is still not correct: For example, since shorts are twice as long as bytes your header will be 22, not 44. I can't check it for every problem, but my answer is correct: i have told you what to do with the audio data, if you can't figure out the rest, you should maybe open a new question.