# code for buildShortArray for audiomixing

Tags: java, android, audio

I am new to android and i just want to create a `dj` player. but for that the starting step is mixing two files. The rough code for that i found on the following link but in that i did not understand how to code for buildShortArray(music1).

I already tried this code but got stuck in the above mentioned method's code.

thank you in advance for help.

Docs here:[Mix two files audio wav on android use short array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853334/mix-two-files-audio-wav-on-android-use-short-array)

Comment: Can you post some code with your problem. That way people can help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code from the link does not show the buildShortArray method.

You need to transform `List<Short>` into array `short[]`:

```
List<Short> music1 = ...;
short[] arrayMusic1 = buildShortArray(music1);
```

You could write the method buildShortArray like this:

```
public short[] buildShortArray(List<Short> list) {

    short[] array = new short[list.size()];

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        array[i] = list.get(i);
    }

    return array;
}
```

However, i'd like to warn you, copy-pasting code is never a good idea.